# Middle numbers in O(log n) time in Swift

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, swift3

I have an algorithm that finds median of two large sorted arrays in `O(log n)` but How can I return the middle two numbers that give the median instead, in the same time complexity? Eg: Given `array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 62, 77]` and `array2 = [ 17, 27, 33, 89, 600, 700, 900]`, should return 33, 50.

My code to finding the median: I having trouble modifying it to only return median numbers.

```
class FindMedianSortedArrays {

    func findMedian(input: [Int], startIndex: Int, endINdex: Int) -> Double {

        let indexDifference = (endINdex - startIndex)
        if indexDifference % 2 == 0 {
            return Double(input[startIndex + (indexDifference/2)])
        } else {
            return Double(input[startIndex + (indexDifference/2)] + input[startIndex + (indexDifference/2) + 1])/2.0
        }
    }



    func findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: [Int], inputB: [Int], startIndexA: Int, endIndexA: Int, startIndexB: Int, endIndexB: Int) -> Double {
        var startIndexA = startIndexA
        var endIndexA   = endIndexA
        var startIndexB = startIndexB
        var endIndexB   = endIndexB

        if ((endIndexA - startIndexA) < 0) || ((endIndexB - startIndexB) < 0) {
            print("Invalid Input")
        }

        if (endIndexA - startIndexA == 0) && (endIndexB - startIndexB == 0) {
            return Double(inputA[0] + inputB[0])/2.0
        }

        if endIndexA - startIndexA == 1 && endIndexB - startIndexB == 1 {
            return Double(max(inputA[startIndexA], inputB[startIndexB]) + min(inputA[endIndexA], inputB[endIndexB]))/2.0
        }

        let medianA: Double = findMedian(input: inputA, startIndex: startIndexA, endINdex: endIndexA)
        let medianB: Double = findMedian(input: inputB, startIndex: startIndexB, endINdex: endIndexB)

        //our second base case
        if medianB == medianA {
            return medianB //return either medianA or medianB
        }

        //since medianA <= median <= medianB, 
        //eliminate elements less than medianA and greater than medB
        if medianA < medianB {
            if((endIndexA - startIndexA) % 2 == 0) {
            startIndexA = startIndexA + (endIndexA - startIndexA)/2
            endIndexB   = startIndexB + (endIndexB - startIndexB)/2
            } else {
                startIndexA = startIndexA + (endIndexA - startIndexA) / 2
                endIndexB = startIndexB + (endIndexB - startIndexB) / 2 + 1
            }
        }

        //since medianB <= median <= medianA, eliminate elements less 
        //than medianB and greater than medianA to narrow down the search.

        else {
            if ((endIndexB - startIndexB) % 2 == 0) {
                startIndexB = startIndexB + (endIndexB - startIndexB)/2
                endIndexA = startIndexA + (endIndexA - startIndexA) / 2 + 1
            }
        }
        return findMedianInSortedArray(inputA:inputA,       inputB: inputB, startIndexA: startIndexA, endIndexA:endIndexA, startIndexB: startIndexB, endIndexB: endIndexB)
    }
}
```

Comment: are the items in array1 unique? or is there a chance to have something like this [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 50, 50, 62, 77]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

class FindMiddleNumbersInSortedArray {

    func findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: [Int], inputB: [Int], startIndexA: Int, endIndexA: Int, startIndexB: Int, endIndexB: Int) -> [Int] {

        var medianNumbers:[Int] = []
       //make sure arrays have the same size
        guard inputA.count == inputB.count else { return medianNumbers }

        var startIndexA = startIndexA
        var endIndexA   = endIndexA
        var startIndexB = startIndexB
        var endIndexB   = endIndexB
        //make sure the user provides right indexes: start and end
        if ((endIndexA - startIndexA) < 0) || ((endIndexB - startIndexB) < 0) {
            fatalError("Invalid Input indexes")
        }
        //if medianA == medianB, we are done, we can append either one twice or both
        if (endIndexA - startIndexA == 0) && (endIndexB - startIndexB == 0) {
            medianNumbers.append(inputA[0])
            medianNumbers.append(inputB[0])
            return medianNumbers        }
        /*if the size == 1, then median = max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1],
        ar2[1]))/2.0 */
        if endIndexA - startIndexA == 1 && endIndexB - startIndexB == 1 {
            medianNumbers.append(max(inputA[startIndexA], inputB[startIndexB]))
            medianNumbers.append( min(inputA[endIndexA], inputB[endIndexB]))
            return medianNumbers
        }

        let medianA = findMedian(input: inputA, startIndex: startIndexA, endIndex: endIndexA)
        let medianB = findMedian(input: inputB, startIndex: startIndexB, endIndex: endIndexB)

        if medianB == medianA {

            medianNumbers.append(Int(medianA))
            medianNumbers.append(Int(medianB))
            return medianNumbers        }

        let medianAIndex = (startIndexA + endIndexA) / 2
        let medianBIndex = (startIndexB + endIndexB) / 2
        //if medianB>medianA, median is in inputA[n/2...n-1] & inputB[0...n/2]
        if medianB > medianA {
            if((endIndexA - startIndexA) % 2 == 0) {
                startIndexA = medianAIndex
                endIndexB = medianBIndex
            } else {
                startIndexA = medianAIndex
                endIndexB = medianBIndex + 1
            }

            //else median is in inputA[0...n/2] and inputB[n/2...n-1] subarrays
        } else {
            if((endIndexA - startIndexA) % 2 == 0) {
                endIndexA = medianAIndex
                startIndexB = medianBIndex
            } else {
                endIndexA = medianAIndex + 1
                startIndexB = medianBIndex
            }
        }

        return findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: inputA, inputB: inputB, startIndexA: startIndexA, endIndexA: endIndexA, startIndexB: startIndexB, endIndexB: endIndexB)
    }

    func findMedian(input: [Int], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) -> Double {
        let indexMid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2
        let indexDifference = (endIndex - startIndex)
        if indexDifference % 2 == 1 {
            return Double(input[indexMid+1]+input[indexMid])/2.0
        } else {
            return Double(input[indexMid])
        }
    }


    //test the code
    func testWithExample(inputA: [Int], inputB: [Int]) {
        print("=====Example=====")
        print("InputA: \(inputA)")
        print("InputB: \(inputB)")
        print("Median numbers: ", findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: inputA, inputB: inputB, startIndexA: 0, endIndexA: inputA.count - 1, startIndexB: 0, endIndexB: inputA.count - 1))
    }

}

//test the program
let medianNumbers = FindMiddleNumbersInSortedArray()
let input1 = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 51, 61, 71]
let input2 = [ 15, 25, 31, 86, 600, 700, 900]
medianNumbers.testWithExample(inputA: input1, inputB: input2)
```

Comment: This should run in 0(lgn)

Answer (score 0):

Finding the middle number(s) of two sorted arrays is `O(n)`. Pseudo Code sample:

```
index1 = 0
index2 = 0

for count = 0 to ( array1.count + array2.count ) / 2
    if array1[index1] < array2[index2] then
        index1 = index1 + 1
    else
        index2 = index2 + 1

median1 = array1[index1]
median2 = array2[index2]
```

The above sample is obviously not completely correct and doesn't handle the edge cases, but should be enough to give you the overall idea.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Solution :

Try below code, I have tested with below examples.

---

```
//tested examples
example(inputA: [1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 62, 77],
            inputB: [ 17, 27, 33, 89, 600, 700, 900])
// result: [33 50]

example(inputA: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20],
             inputB: [10, 11, 12, 14, 20])
// result : [12, 13]

example(inputA: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 800],
            inputB: [10, 11, 12, 14, 20, 21, 900])
// result : [13, 14]

example(inputA: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            inputB: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
// return [7, 5]

func example(inputA: [Int], inputB: [Int]) {
    print("---Example----")
    print(inputA)
    print(inputB)
    print(findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: inputA, inputB: inputB, startIndexA: 0, endIndexA: inputA.count-1, startIndexB: 0, endIndexB: inputB.count-1))
}
```

---

```
func findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: [Int], inputB: [Int], startIndexA: Int, endIndexA: Int, startIndexB: Int, endIndexB: Int) -> [Int] {
    var findMedianNumArr:[Int] = []

    var startIndexA = startIndexA
    var endIndexA   = endIndexA
    var startIndexB = startIndexB
    var endIndexB   = endIndexB

    if ((endIndexA - startIndexA) < 0) || ((endIndexB - startIndexB) < 0) {
        print("Invalid Input")
    }

    if (endIndexA - startIndexA == 0) && (endIndexB - startIndexB == 0) {
        findMedianNumArr.append(inputA[0])
        findMedianNumArr.append(inputB[0])
        return findMedianNumArr
    }

    if endIndexA - startIndexA == 1 && endIndexB - startIndexB == 1 {
        findMedianNumArr.append(max(inputA[startIndexA], inputB[startIndexB]))
        findMedianNumArr.append( min(inputA[endIndexA], inputB[endIndexB]))
        return findMedianNumArr
    }

    let medianA = findMedian(input: inputA, startIndex: startIndexA, endIndex: endIndexA)
    let medianB = findMedian(input: inputB, startIndex: startIndexB, endIndex: endIndexB)

    if medianB == medianA {
        let medianArrA = findMedianArray(input: inputA, startIndex: startIndexA, endIndex: endIndexA)
        let medianArrB = findMedianArray(input: inputB, startIndex: startIndexB, endIndex: endIndexB)
        findMedianNumArr.append(contentsOf: medianArrA)
        findMedianNumArr.append(contentsOf: medianArrB)
        return findMedianNumArr
    }

    let medianAIndex = (startIndexA + endIndexA) / 2
    let medianBIndex = (startIndexB + endIndexB) / 2
    if medianB > medianA {
        if((endIndexA - startIndexA) % 2 == 0) {
            startIndexA = medianAIndex
            endIndexB = medianBIndex
        } else {
            startIndexA = medianAIndex
            endIndexB = medianBIndex + 1
        }
    } else {
        if((endIndexA - startIndexA) % 2 == 0) {
            endIndexA = medianAIndex
            startIndexB = medianBIndex
        } else {
            endIndexA = medianAIndex + 1
            startIndexB = medianBIndex
        }
    }

    return findMedianInSortedArray(inputA: inputA, inputB: inputB, startIndexA: startIndexA, endIndexA: endIndexA, startIndexB: startIndexB, endIndexB: endIndexB)
}

func findMedian(input: [Int], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) -> Double {
    let indexMid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2
    let indexDifference = (endIndex - startIndex)
    if indexDifference % 2 == 1 {
        return Double(input[indexMid+1]+input[indexMid])/2.0
    } else {
        return Double(input[indexMid])
    }
}

func findMedianArray(input: [Int], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) -> [Int] {
    var findMedianNumArr:[Int] = []

    let indexMid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2
    let indexDifference = (endIndex - startIndex)
    if indexDifference % 2 == 1 {
        findMedianNumArr.append(input[indexMid+1])
    }
    findMedianNumArr.append(input[indexMid])
    return findMedianNumArr
}
```

Comment: And what would be the time complexity? I think sorted() runs 0(n) but I am not sure.

Comment: I think this solution has a time complexity of 0(n log n), which is not acceptable in this situation. At least 0(n)

Comment: @gsmax2017 please check the updated solution, removed sorted()

Comment: It works, however time and space I am trying to see if there could be an improvement. But  this works! thanks @Vini App